# react native maps multiple marker problem

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-maps

Im trying to add multiple marker on my map with use Array.map(). But error occured.

**Code Block:**

```
          <MapView
            key={'map'}
            showsUserLocation
            provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
            style={styles.map}
            region={{
              latitude: 38.439607,
              longitude: 34.884025,
              latitudeDelta: 1,
              longitudeDelta: 16,
            }}>
            { carListStore.car.map((data,index) => {
              return(
                <>
                <Marker
                key={data}
                coordinate={{
                  latitude: (data.LT !== null) ? data.LT: 0, 
                  longitude:(data.LG !== null) ? data.LG: 0
                  }}
                title={data.P}
                description={ data.SP +' km/h'}>
                <Image key={index} source={driverLogo} resizeMethod='scale' resizeMode='contain' style={{width:45, height:45}} />
              </Marker>
              </>
              )
            })}
          </MapView>
```

***carListStore.car*
data**

```
{"DD": "359,3", "DR": "-", "DS": "102441.8", "ID": "39382", "KT": "2022-09-15 18:13:28", "LG": "29.215014", "LT": "40.200127", "P": "22", "PH1": null, "PH2": null, "PT": "", "SP": "14", "ST": "success"}
```

(this is one of sample object from array)

***And ERROR!***
*( This is not shown in terminal)*

[image: error from emulator screen. This is not shown in terminal]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey you should convert your `longitude` and `latitude` to Double via `parseFloat`.

```
<Marker
                key={data}
                coordinate={{
                  latitude: (data.LT !== null) ? parseFloat(data.LT): 0, 
                  longitude:(data.LG !== null) ? parseFloat(data.LG): 0
                  }}
                title={data.P}
                description={ data.SP +' km/h'}>
```

Try this, and lemme know in case of any concerns.